# Generate Normal random numbers with deviation form 0.02 to 0.2 in matlab

Tags: matlab, random

How I can generate normal random numbers with deviation form 0.02 to 0.2 in MATLAB? I tried the following, but am getting an error :

```
dev = 0.02:0.02:0.2  
x = random('Normal',1,dev,8,1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
dev = 0.02:0.02:0.2; 
randNumbersCell = arrayfun(@(d) random('Normal', 1, d, 8, 1), dev, 'UniformOutput', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just use a simple for-loop. No need for anything fancy here:

```
dev = 0.02:0.02:0.2  
n = length(dev);
x = zeros(8,n);
for col = 1:n
    x(:, col) = random('Normal',1,dev(col),8,1)  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 10 values for the standard deviation, and I assume you want 8 random values for each.

```
dev = 0.02:0.02:0.2; %// standard deviation values
mu = 1; %// mean
m = 8; %// desired number of random values for each standard deviation

result = mu + bsxfun(@times, dev(:), randn(1,m));
```

This works multiplying a "standard" random variable (mean 0, deviation 1) times the desired deviation, and then adding the desired mean.